# How to hide events and show view more modal in fullcalendar.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, fullcalendar

I had spent three days reading documentation, and like six days testing ways to do what we want to fulfill.

I still don't know how to emulate the view more...

Here is a piece of the code I have so far (Is really long)

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: ''
              },
        navLinks: true,
        timeFormat: 'h:mm A',
                      editable: true,
              eventLimit: true,
                eventOrder: "-sorting",

        events: [
        /* Lot of Events Here */
                   ],

        eventRender: function(event, element) {

            $(element).hide();
            $(".fc-day").on('click',function(){
              console.log($(this));
            });


});
```

The question per se would be how do we trigger the view more when clicking the day box (not the event)???

Comment: do you mean you want to go to any individual date? `.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date )`

Comment: @Rikin no, just how to make that the view more modal shows, even if there is only 1 event, and hide the color bars

Comment: have you checked what function is triggered by clicking the built-in "view more" button (bear in mind you can set it to have various different functions)? All you need to do is fire the same function in the "dayClick" callback. I should think you can use your browser's developer tools to trace it, should be a fairly simple bit of reverse-engineering.

Comment: @ADyson I have tried that, 6 days, can't find it...

Comment: In https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.js go to line 7826, you can see the event handler which is bound to the built-in "more" link (the element is `<a class="fc-more">` in the rendered calendar). By default the handler calls the "showSegPopover" method to display the popover. You can study the source of that to work out what you need to emulate. I just found it by searching the code for "fc-more-popover" (looking for the class given to the popover element, because logically it would lead to the code which generates it). Not too hard to find.